# Address not appending to array

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I'm new to Ethereum and I communicate with my Solidity using Go language.  I have a contract that allows user to join the lottery by adding the user's address to the array of addresses, but it's only the address that deployed the contract that gets added to the array.  Subsequent ones don't reflect.  Below are my code snippets.

Solidity code:

```solidity
pragma solidity >=0.5.2 <0.6.0;

contract lottery {
  address public manager;
  address[] public players;
  string private managerRestriction = "Managers are not allowed in competition";
  string private playerRestriction = "Only manager can select winner";

  constructor() public {
    manager = msg.sender;
  }

  function allPlayer() public view returns (address[] memory){
    return players;
  }

  function enter() public payable {
    players.push(msg.sender);
  }

  function randomGenerator() private view returns (uint) {
    return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, now, players)));
  }

  function selectWinner() public restrictPlayer returns (address) {
    uint index = randomGenerator() % players.length;
    address payable selectedPlayer = address(uint160(players[index]));
    selectedPlayer.transfer(address(this).balance);
    players = new address[](0);
    return selectedPlayer;
  }

  modifier restrictManager() {
    require(msg.sender != manager, managerRestriction);
    _;
  }

  modifier restrictPlayer() {
    require(msg.sender == manager, playerRestriction);
    _;
  }
}
```

My handler that communicates with abi:

```golang
package lottery

import (
  "context"
  "log"
  "math/big"
  "os"

  "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind"
  "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
  "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
  "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
  "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

var myEnv map[string]string

type Handler struct {
  Ctx     context.Context
  Session LotterySession
  Client  *ethclient.Client
  Local   bool
} 

func loadEnv() {
  var err error
  if myEnv, err = godotenv.Read(".env"); err != nil {
    log.Printf("Could not load env: %v ", err)
  }
}

func (h *Handler) NewHandler(keystore, keypass string) LotterySession {
  loadEnv()
  var auth *bind.TransactOpts
  switch h.Local {
  case true:
    keyStore, err := os.Open(myEnv[keystore])
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatalf("Error getting keystore from env: %v", err)
    }

    defer keyStore.Close()

    keyPass := myEnv[keypass]
    auth, err = bind.NewTransactor(keyStore, keyPass)
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatalf("Error occured: %v", err)
    }

  default:
    privateKey, err := crypto.HexToECDSA(myEnv[""])
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatalf("Error loading private key from env: %v", err)
    }
    auth = bind.NewKeyedTransactor(privateKey)
  }

  auth.Nonce = big.NewInt(2)
  auth.GasLimit = 3000000
  auth.GasPrice = big.NewInt(1000000)

  return LotterySession{
    TransactOpts: *auth,
    CallOpts: bind.CallOpts{
      From: auth.From,
      Context: h.Ctx,
    },
  }
}

func (h *Handler) DeployContract() LotterySession {
  loadEnv()
  address, tx, instance, err := DeployLottery(&h.Session.TransactOpts, h.Client)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Deployment error occured: %v", err)
  }
  switch h.Local {
  case true:
    updateEnv("LOCAL_ADDRESS", address.Hex())
  default:
    updateEnv("ADDRESS", address.Hex())
  }
  h.Session.Contract = instance
  log.Println("Contract Deployed! Transaction hash: %s", 
  tx.Hash().Hex())
  return h.Session
}

func (h . *Handler) LoadContract() LotterySession {
  var address common.Address
  switch h.Local {
  case true:
    address = common.HexToAddress(myEnv["LOCAL_ADDRESS"])
  default:
    address = common.HexToAddress(myEnv["ADDRESS"])
  }
  instance, err := NewLottery(address, h.Client)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to load contract: %v", err)
  }

  h.Session.Contract = instance
  return h.Session
}

func (h *Handler) GetAllPlayer() ([]common.Address, error) {
  return h.Session.AllPlayer()
}

func (h *Handler) JoinLottery() (string, error) {
  tx, err := h.Session.Enter()
  if err != nil {
    return "", err
  }
  return tx.Hash().Hex(), nil
}

func (h *Handler) GetManager() string {
  add, _ := h.Session.Manager()
  return add.Hex()
}

func (h *Handler) SelectWinner() (string, error) {
  tx, err := h.Session.SelectWinner()
  if err != nil {
    return "", err
  }
  return tx.Hash().Hex(), nil
}

func updateEnv(key string, value string) {
  myEnv[key] = value
  if err := godotenv.Write(myEnv, ".env"); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to update env: %v", err)
  }
}
```

Main.go

```golang
package main

import (
  "context"
  "fmt"
  "log"
  "os"

  "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
  "github.com/joho/godotenv"
  "github.com/olugbokikisemiu/Lottery/lottery"
)

func main() {
  if err := godotenv.Load(); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Could not load env: %v", err)
  }

  c := context.Background()

  client, err := ethclient.Dial(os.Getenv("LOCAL_GATEWAY"))
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Could not load env: %v", err)
  }

  defer client.Close()

  lotterySession := &lottery.Handler{
    Ctx:    c,
    Client: client,
    Local:  true,
  }

  lotterySession.Session = lotterySession.NewHandler("KEYSTORE2", "KEYPASS2")
  lotterySession.LoadContract()
  address, err := lotterySession.GetAllPlayer()
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error %v\n ", err)
  }
  fmt.Println("address", address)
}
```

I will really appreciate all the help I can get because I've been stuck here for 3 days.

Comment: The `players` array is already a dynamic (storage) array; get rid of `players = new address[](0)`. Change it to `players.length = 0`.

Comment: your enter function work correctly, but idk how you change the msg sender address with go, anyway maybe it will be easier to give the address as parameter in the function enter:  function enter(address playerAddress) public payable {
    players.push(playerAddress);
  }

Comment: @MajdTL, thanks for your comment. Kindly check NewHandler() func in handler.go, that's how i change the address by passing the keystore and password which i read from env. I will consider your suggestion and see if it works well.

Comment: @goodvibration, thanks for the observation

Comment: @MajdTL, i tried your suggestion, it still didn't append, can it be the way i setup my account. i tried getting the transaction after joining the lottery and this is the response

Comment: {
  blockHash: null,
  blockNumber: null,
  from: "0xd264600fd6221350e9ac9ce233153e7f23cbe296",
  gas: 3000000,
  gasPrice: 1000000,
  hash: "0xdfb082fea5120f3a6dd78de08eee97495bfc910177abc18d45545ec7de5ef539",
  input: "0xd014c01f000000000000000000000000d264600fd6221350e9ac9ce233153e7f23cbe296",
  nonce: 3,
  r: "0xbb33ac2eb5fc2031912d3265a14b25794c8e1953574fcd2813c53aa082818d10",
  s: "0x1695770d2f73fea2aa73e10d21a7c9cea7ffbbde06d722346e3ade3d828dcdea",
  to: "0x3520a179bddba37780f3a95e3b815b58c16b9ac0",

Comment: Why your block number is null ?, Try to use ganache as your simulated blockchain instead of geth

Comment: @MajdTL, thanks for the response, please do you have any resource that can help in setting up ganache and does it work with go because most the tutorials i've seen used Javascript

Comment: see here in using ganache section, you should just change the gateway https://goethereumbook.org/en/client-setup/ , i can help you more at the weekend, write a respone at friday to remind me. (use better the ganache application, make sure you have generated enough accounts with balances and take care the accounts are unlocked

Comment: Thanks so much @MajdTL, i really appreciate. I will like to have any of your social media contact details if you don't mind for swift conversation

Comment: You still have that problem ?

Comment: @MajdTL sorry for the late response, i have not been available for the past 2weeks. Yeah, ganache works fine. Thank you so much !!!!!

Comment: The accounts on ganache are not locked( you can change this option), so maybe your problem was with sign the transaction or blanaces